# Android Studio Electric eel | Debugger always stuck on "waiting for the process to finish gracefully"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-electric-eel

Like the title says I am on Android Studio Electric eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1 and whenever I start the debugger it works for 1 or 2 breakpoints, after that the app goes to ANR, and watchers get stuck on evaluating.
When stopping the debugger gets a pop with "waiting for the process to finish gracefully".
I tried to invalidate the cache and clear all the breakpoints but still had no luck. The same project was working fine on AS last update.

Comment: I also get this issue on Electric Eel, not all the time but probably 50% of the time that I debug with breakpoints. It's very annoying. Any updates on a fix for this?

Comment: Same issue using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1

Comment: Are you using Realm?

Comment: @destresa No, I'm not.

Comment: @shine_joseph for me, this issue always appears when I set breakpoints into lines that use syncrhonized realm objects. If I first copy objects from realm or use plain objects does not happen.

Comment: Same issue on Hedgehog...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had tried to change the suspend breakpoints setting from `all` to `Thread` and the debugger was worked normally. You can make that setting to default so that you don't need to switch for every breakpoints. Here is the screenshot of the settings:

[image: breakpoint settings]

Comment: Yep. worked, thanks a lot.